# Getting to "a" tags to modify them in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
</body>
<div class="exercise ex1">
    <h1>Zadanie 1</h1>
    <div>
        <h3>Chrome</h3>
        <div class="chrome"></div>
        <a href="https://www.google.pl/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html">Opera</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Microsoft Edge</h3>
        <div class="edge"></div>
        <a href="www.github.pl">Microsoft Edge</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Firefox</h3>
        <div class="firefox"></div>
        <a href="www.coderslab.pl">Opera</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have no idea, how to get to my a tags, so I could change their inner HTML and hrefs in JavaScript. I'll be very grateful for your help!

Comment: If you want just links, as opposed to anchors without a href, then [*document.links*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#dom-document-links) provides an HTMLCollection of all links in the document in document order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll("a")` and a `for` loop to iterate all `a` elements in document.

Note, appear to be missing `<html>` tag , first `body` element tag should be `<body>` , not closing `</body>` tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="exercise ex1">
    <h1>Zadanie 1</h1>
    <div>
        <h3>Chrome</h3>
        <div class="chrome"></div>
        <a href="https://www.google.pl/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html">Opera</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Microsoft Edge</h3>
        <div class="edge"></div>
        <a href="www.github.pl">Microsoft Edge</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Firefox</h3>
        <div class="firefox"></div>
        <a href="www.coderslab.pl">Opera</a>
    </div>
</div>
  <script>
    var a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      console.log(a[i], a[i].innerHTML, a[i].href)
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("A")
```

which returns a collection of elements - more specifically, a NodeList object. This can then be accessed in a similar manner to an array:

```
var allAs = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
console.log(allAs[0].href); //will print "https://www.google.pl/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html"
```

If you want to know more about how to use this, read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName` does not return an array

Comment: @guest271314It does? check out my jsFiddle

Comment: It may *look* like an array but if you read the spec on it, you'll see that it's technically not an array

Comment: @5parc it is an *"array like object"* that has length and you can iterate in loop but can't use array methods on

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, it's full of errors and poor advice. Use the relevant W3C specification or MDN for examples.

Comment: Ah really? I've always found it to be ok while I'm learning the basics - but I've switched the link anyway!

Comment: @charlietfl An interesting read! I'll need to keep that in mind from now on haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As millerbr pointed out, `document.getElementsByTagName("A")` will return an array like object. You can then edit the hrefs innerHTML by going `document.getElementsByTagName("A")[0].innerHTML = "NotChrome"`

Check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqud265n/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over the elements

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for ( var i = anchors.length; i--; ) {
    anchors[i].innerHTML = 'something else';
    anchors[i].href = 'http://someother_url.com'; 
}
```

Comment: A elements aren't necessarily links. If they are a link target or anchor, they'll have an ID (or name and ID) but no href. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the links in a document using the [*document.links* collection](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#dom-document-links), which contains all A and MAP elements with an href attribute, e.g.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.links, function(link) {
  console.log(link.href);
});
```

Note that A elements without an href aren't links, they're anchors (i.e. they are the target of a link). Using `getElementsByTagName('a')` will return all A elements, including those that aren't links.